# what does row oriented and column oriented mean in matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, qr-decomposition

I am reading the paper "[Numerics of Gram Schmidt orthogonal](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594904936)", Then I noticed there are some terminologies that I can't understand which are "**row-oriented**" and "**column-oriented**" located at P299 in the paper.

the original sentence is "In row-oriented MGS a sequence of matrices, **A=A1, A2, ..., An** is computed...".

I googled and found that "row/column-oriented" is mainly used in databases. one prone-understandable source is [this post](https://dataschool.com/data-modeling-101/row-vs-column-oriented-databases/).

Then I found that "row/column-major" in matrix theory which I can understand is the store-type in your computer that can be found in [this post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order). based on the context of where it appears in the paper I am pretty sure "row/column-oriented" is not "row/column-major". (If so why does the algorithm still access data by column in the "row_oriented" matrix?)

Comment: Glancing a the GS Wiki page, I see calculations that iterate on the columns of the matrix ("vectors").  So I can imagine iterating on the rows instead.  This isn't a matter of array storage, but calculation methods.

Comment: Why the `sparse-matrix` tag?  Sparse matrices can be stored in CSR, Compressed Sparse Row matrix format.  The alternative is CSC, That's a storage method that's useful for calculations.  But it isn't part of GS - unless you are doing GS on a sparse matrix.

Comment: sry mate, I am afraid that your understanding from Wiki is not matched the meaning in the paper. In the row version, we subtract every a_j's projection on the current q every iteration. In the column version, we subtract a_j's projection on every q which has already been computed every iteration. The detail code could be checked in : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkMhK.jpg (originated by the paper).

Comment: As for your second question, I found these terminologies are also appeared in some papers talking about sparse matrices which used GPU to accelerate computing.